# Is it ok to embed `dl` in `ul`

Tags: html

I want to have a list that is a regular `ul` list, and in each `li` to have a key/value pair. I was thinking that it would be ok to embed a `dl` in the `ul` something like...

```
<ul><dl>
    <li><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></li>
    <li><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></li>
    <li><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></li>
    <li><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></li>
</dl></ul>
```

### Is this against specs in any way?

EDIT: inspired by @pwdst's comment...

Is there anything wrong with having lots of single entry `dl`s in a `ul`/`li`?

```
<ul>
    <li><dl><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></dl></li>
    <li><dl><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></dl></li>
    <li><dl><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></dl></li>
    <li><dl><dt>key</dt>: <dd>value</dd></dl></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

Comment: @rid thanks for the feedback. Re: using `dl` instead of `ul`... if that was an option, I would not need to ask the question. It is obviously the `normal` way to approach these things. However, as I state at the start of my question... `I want to have a list that is a regular ul list`...

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid. The specific error from the W3C Validator was *"Element dl not allowed as child of element ul in this context."*.

You should instead write:

```
<dl>
  <dt>key</dt>
  <dd>value</dd>
  <dt>key</dt>
  <dd>value</dd>
  <dt>key</dt>
  <dd>value</dd>
</dl>
```

You can then style this however you like with CSS.